# Comparing growth of piecewise functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I was working through CLRS to beef up my theoretical skills. It spends a while discussing how to compare two different growth functions, but I came up with an example which I can't solve.

let g1(n) = n if n is odd; n<sup>2</sup> if n is even

let g2(n) = n<sup>2</sup> if n is odd; n if n is even

In terms of long term growth, how are g1 and g2 related? I want to say g1 = θ(g2), but I have no idea how to show (prove) it.

Comment: Two functions need not be related by any of the Big-O-type relationships.  Also, Theta() is a strong condition -- it would make sense to try to prove a function is O() and Omega() separately first.  If you can find a counterexample for *either*, then the function can't be Theta().

Comment: g1 and g2 are unrelated, even though they both belong to Ω(n) and O(n²).

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that:

- Both g1(n) and g2(n) are having the tightest upper bound of O(n<sup>2</sup>), therefore they can both be written as O(n<sup>2</sup>).
- Both g1(n) and g2(n) are having the tightest lower bound of O(n), therefore they both can be written as Ω(n).

---

The functions g1(n) and g2(n) are written in such a way that they have different upper and lower bounds. It means there is no function g(n) for which:

1. either, `c11*g(n) < g1(n) < c12*g(n)` holds true;
2. or, `c21*g(n) < g2(n) < c22*g(n)` holds true.

---

Since, neither g1(n) nor g2(n) can be expressed as θ(g(n)) for any function of n whatsoever, therefore **g1(n) cannot be θ(g2(n)) or vice versa**